# Access OneDrive personal vault through API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

Microsoft introduced a special folder in OneDrive (I only see it in a personal OneDrive account, not in OneDrive for Business) called ["Personal Vault"](https://www.engadget.com/2019/10/01/microsoft-onedrive-personal-vault/). I searched the [documentation of MS Graph API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/overview) but could not find this mentioned.

So my question is: is there any way to access this personal vault as a third-party app?

Answer (score 1):

Same problem here.

Funny thing is that:

1. It does not appear in the [root children](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/root/children)
2. It appears if you call the [delta API](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/root/delta) where you can see a folder with the
   `specialFolder` attribute not null and whose `specialFolder.name` is
   "vault". This specialFolder, though, has the `deleted` facet, with the
   state set to "hardDeleted". If you extract the ID from the delta API
   call and try to address the folder directly with
   `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/items/{id}`, however, you
   get an access denied error